# Search for folders then create a shortcut to a directory

Tags: javascript, function, search, directory, shortcut

I need to be able to find every folder beginning with "max_" at one time, and create a shortcut from those folders to another director. I'm using a simple web app to do this. I have a search box to find the user and button to create the shortcut. Any ideas on how to go about this would be great. Folder names: max_1 max_2, max_3, sam_1, sam_2, sam_3

```js
var createShortcut = document.getElementById("button-create");

createShortcut.addEventListener("click", myButtonFunction);

function myButtonFunction() {
  document.getElementById("button-create").innerHTML = "Created";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Shortcut</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-main">
    <label for="search">Search Users</label><br>

    <input type="text" placeholder="ex. user_" id="text-id" class="text-class"><br>

    <label>Create Shortcut</label><br>

    <div class="containter-buttons">

      <button type="button" class="button-Icon" id="button-create">Create Shortcut</button><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to access the user's folders? Or the folders within the operating system in which your web application is located?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. That's where the shortcut will be created in.

It will be created within each of the max_ folders to a single location.